# How to debug ANT + JAVA project in visual code IDE

Tags: java, ant, visual-studio-code

My project is running smoothly in visual code [Tomcat].
But when it comes to debugging it, I have tried adding launch.json and add configuration to it as follows :-

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "mainClass": "full qualified name",
        "args": ""
    }]}
```

after pressing F5 for starting debugging, getting error as

> Cannot create debug adapter (no executable specified in package.json)

So, Is there any other way to do it ? Need some suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some reason you're trying to develop java application in VS Code? Why not use a java ide(IntelliJ, Netbeans, Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error whilst trying to debug standalone java files after following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46128218/7066647). You do not need to do this anymore as VS Code automatically generates the file `.vscode/launch.json` under the current directory.

In reality, the debugger was not working for another reason. I had installed the [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) but not the [RedHat OpenJDK](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download/) and it is required by [The Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java).